# How to Store Incidental Information Gleaned in the Course of Conducting Research

Tags: research-process, open-science, backup-archiving

I'm in the throes of writing my first substantial research paper in the field of Information Science. The topic looks promising and my advisor seems pleased with the work. Because of the nature of the work, there are a lot of intermediate steps involved in obtaining the raw data, preprocessing the data, then running the experiment proper and recording the results. These intermediate steps involved a lot of programming on my part, building one-shot tools to solve problems along the way to conducting the experiments.

I understand that reproducibility is a huge issue in computer science and I wish to lessen the burden upon my future self and upon my lab mates if/when the time comes to follow up on this trail of experiments. Certain software has to be installed, path variables have to be configured, firewall settings have to be set up to allow transference of data - and similar technical problems that wouldn't be appropriate to include in the resultant research paper proper.

How do I record all of these technical and procedural steps such that a future interested party (be it myself or one of my lab mates, or perhaps even an outsider to the lab who has an academic interest in the resultant paper and software) can reproduce the experiment? Do I leave myself open to being "scooped" if I set up a website with an academic blog or wiki in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are excellent questions! You are especially wise to recognize that your future self will have unfortunately hazy memories of what parameters you chose and why. (I've also been mulling this process myself, and was considering asking a similar question!) Your question is definitely related to prior questions here, but I think those don't necessarily cover collecting data, and some of the answers haven't aged as gracefully as others because they deal with "try this kind of software."

To the extent that your advisor and lab already have a workflow set up, try to work this into it. Is there a shared server for documents, or an application like Dropbox or Box? Do you have a shared Zotero group for bibliography and files? Do you use Git or other version control software? (Version control may be less relevant to you if you're the only one working on the code, whereas it will be critical if multiple people fiddle with it.)

**Keeping notes about results**

Many scientists are trained to use research notebooks, and there have been interesting discussions about those; [aeismail](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/83/good-practices-for-organizing-notes) suggested [Colin Purrington's tips on maintaining a lab notebook](http://colinpurrington.com/tips/lab-notebooks). From looking at an [excellent question across tools](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/46228/im-looking-for-an-application-or-workflow-which-integrates-data-values-into-the/75775) and [a question about Python in particular](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/758/tools-and-protocol-for-reproducible-data-science-using-python/759#759) (though it can be extended), Jupyter is the next tool I will look into for myself, and it may be what you're looking for.

For my own dissertation, for tables and charts I created in Stata, I had a clear file naming scheme about where I outputted and saved them. It was easy (conditional on already knowing LaTeX) to make a LaTeX doc that pointed to those files and could update with the newest version of the results.

**File naming and organizing hierarchy**

[TCSGrad](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/87/88197) pointed to [Jason Eisner's advice on file organization](http://www.cs.jhu.edu/~jason/advice/how-to-organize-your-files.html). In particular, I like his advice there of putting in files or file names or folder names the tags: to-do, how-to, logbook, acknowledge, and send-to.
I also highly recommend having, in your project folder, a folder called "Raw Data". This is the original data, as downloaded or found or whatever. In "Raw Data", have a readme doc, whether it is a text file or spreadsheet or whatever, that says where each bit of Raw Data came from, when, under what conditions, etc.

To capture the software setup and system parameters, perhaps have a similar Setup folder (with the executable files for software you install, and a similar readme). ([Docker](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/758/tools-and-protocol-for-reproducible-data-science-using-python/775#775) is one tool to capture and easily replicate the correct computing environment. A group like [Software Carpentry](https://software-carpentry.org/) might be able to provide guidance.)

A separate "Data" folder can have your cleaned versions of the raw data, and folders for "Code" and "Output" should be similarly separate. (Datasets you create should still go into Data, probably.) You might even find it useful to have separate folders for (nicely formatted) "Tables" and "Figures".

Whenever you submit something or have a major draft, try to save a copy of all the things you're relying on, as-is.

**Making the notes available?**

[This prior question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/5753/open-lab-notebook-in-early-postdoc-career-advantages-vs-disadvantages) asks about the (dis)advantages of an open lab notebook, and there was some good discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you  definitely DO leave yourself open   to  being  'scooped'  and plagiarized  if you make  a   blog  or  wiki  site..

Whatever  you   do     and  however  you  take notes  or make  records  FOR YOURSELF and  your  adviser,  DO NOT PUT THEM ONLINE.   you  cn make  hand  written notes  or  you  can  make  word   files  or  whatever   and   Save  them,  possibly  burn those   records  or   onto CDs  or  whatever  has   replaced Zip  files in  the    year  20  years.  part of  my   data  is 8mm 
  tape  cassettes   from  Sun   work   station,  but  i know  i probably   was  not  given  all  the 8mm  tapes...  The  text  of  my   thesis  or   on   ZIP  files.  i  didn't have  my  own PC   until  2004.  I did  have    the  hardware  for  the  Zip  files on  that  PC,   but  now  i  am  on mey  second  PC.     which   i  bought   over  the  counter  in

30   years  from  now.     however you  record    and  save your  data   and  research  notes  or notebooks  NOW,  Is  the  hardware  you  use NOW  STILL GOING TO BE AVAILABLE   and  usable  IN     the  future.?  Hardware   DOES   become  outdated.     You've  probably never  used   3.5  inch  floppy  discs.  I have.

My  thesis  was  interdisciplinary    i  had   mainly  geologists   and  my    thesis  committee  ,  but  i  also had  one    geographer,   who  happened  to  be  the GIS   expert   i  was  WELL   aware     that  my 
"audience"   would NOT  be  familiar   with  all   the  image processing, 
 remote   sensing, and geographical cartography  and     computer     and  GIS   terms    and I made   very  sure   i  explained  what  something  like  "normalized   vegetation   index"   meant    and   which   Bands  of  Landsat  satellites images  were  used  t  create  an NDVI   image     were  used   and  how  image  processing   worked     statistically   with  the   data  in  a  satellite   image.  Data  is MEANINGLESS     until  it  is  organized  analyze  and INTERPRETED   to  become  information. oneof  of  my  thesis  committee  members, a  geologist, said  my    thesis  was  well  written  and  not  too full   of   jargon.

HOWEVER  you   record  your  data   and how you  organize  it,  DO NOT put  it  online outside  of   a   very limited sub-network,  and NOT  on   a  blog   or wiki page  that becomes  publicly  accessible..  You DO NOT     want  to put ANYTHING  online  because your  copyright   right WILL  be  violated.

When you  get  to the  the literature   research  par  of   writing your  thesis  or  dissertation, or ANY paper   for  publication,  i  suggest  you  spend  some  time   with  one  or  university   reference  librarians.    Ask   them    how  library digital    databases  work    and   what  citation indices   are,      and  how  you  can  access  them..    Publish or  perish may  be   trite,   but  it  is VERY   true   and yes,  IF  someone   CAN  "scoop'  you They WILL   I've  seen one  person  a Ph.D.  candidate,     who  had  to  stay in   school   another  2  or   3  semesters   because   some  else  got part of    their  dissertation  published  FIRST.   and  THAT   was  in  the  1980s., BEFORE  the internet  took  off  in  the  1990s  and  early
2000s.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I record all of these technical and procedural steps -- including installing certain software, setting path variables, and firewall configuration -- such that a future interested party...can reproduce the experiment?

You can write a script that automates the necessary steps and reproduces the results. (Writing that script after you've produced your results will be difficult. Try writing the script as you go along.)

(Anything more sophisticated is surely complimentary.)